# How do I put each part of my array through a test to return an output?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'm trying to get the testData to be checked by the NHS number checker code below. How do I test each part of the array & get the output?

```
 using System;
public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    {
        //Test loop


        string[] testData = { "1234567890", "4444444444", "7777777777", "77777777", "BRADLEYPAU" };
        foreach (string s in testData)
        {

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }



    Boolean returnValue;
    String NHSNumber;
    //NHSNumber = "9051292074";
    NHSNumber = "7777777777";
    //NHSNumber = "9434765919";
    //NHSNumber = "PAULBRADLE";
    returnValue = isNHSValid(NHSNumber);

    if (returnValue == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(NHSNumber + " looks good");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(NHSNumber + " is invalid!");
    }
}
public static Boolean isNHSValid(string numberToCheck)
{
    if (numberToCheck.Length != 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numberToCheck + " is too long!");
        return false;
    }

    long v;
    if (Int64.TryParse(numberToCheck, out v) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numberToCheck + " contains non numbers!");
        return false;
    }
```

I have tried other examples that are commented out and they work. But now I can't figure out how to do the same thing with an array.

Comment: Have you tried passing `s` to `isNHSValid` method? `var result = isNHSValid(s);` and then check result inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `numberToCheck.Length != 10` does not mean that number to check is too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you could make the tests into a unit test project and call your validation code.

For now, you can move you testing code into the for loop (or another function).
(It will simplify slightly too):

```
public static void Main()
{
    //Test loop

    string[] testData = { "1234567890", "4444444444", "7777777777", "77777777", "BRADLEYPAU" };
    foreach (string NHSNumber in testData)
    {
        if (isNHSValid(NHSNumber)) //note, no need compare with true
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NHSNumber + " looks good");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NHSNumber + " is invalid!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025235/how-do-i-put-each-part-of-my-array-through-a-test-to-return-an-output#comment94886856_54025235), use the loop you created to iterate over each `string` in the array. Then pass each `string` into `isNHSValid`.

```
   string[] testData = { "1234567890", "4444444444", "7777777777", "77777777", "BRADLEYPAU" };
   foreach (string NHSNumber in testData)
   {
       bool returnValue;
       returnValue = isNHSValid(NHSNumber);

       if (returnValue == true)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(NHSNumber + " looks good");
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine(NHSNumber + " is invalid!");
       }
       Console.WriteLine();
   }
```